# How is arrival to the City of Brass resolved?

Tags: city-of-brass

I used to know the answer to this question.  Anyways, I played a round of City of Brass recently and we (well, three of us.  There was a falling out) actually made it to the city, which is unusual for the groups I tend to suggest this game to.  I hadn't had that happen in a while, so I had to consult the rules, but I can't find my old copy and the only online version available seems to be the pre-update version which has a ridiculous end-game mechanic that doesn't even seem to exclude multiple persons from entry into the city.  I vaguely remember there was some kind of vote and being the Leader was important and I think people killed each other battle-royale style and there was an option not to attempt entry.  What's the exact procedure once the city is reached?

Edit:  I had trouble finding the author's site as well.  Turns out he moved to [a new site](http://crngames.com/).  And [released the rules for free](http://crngames.com/crngames/store).

Answer (score 2):

From the updated rulebook:

> If you live through the four acts, you reach the City of Brass. The current
>   Leader describes it bright shining in the sun. He or she must also
>   narrate the party members being split up by forces from the City.
>   (Maybe the interior is a maze. Or maybe armed soldiers separate you.
>   It’s up to the Leader.) Only one of you will be deemed worthy enough to enter the City of
>   Brass.
>
> All living characters are tested to see if they are worthy. Go around in
>   a circle. When it gets to you, if your character is alive, ask “Is so-and-so
>   (your character’s name) worthy to enter the City of Brass?” Everyone
>   votes on this question and you tally the votes. The voters can answer
>   yes to more than one person. As per normal, everyone except
>   you closes their eyes and you tally. You can lie. Call out the result of
>   the vote. If anyone thinks you’re lying, they can exclaim “J’accuse!”
>   Everyone opens their eyes and tallies the votes. If you lied, your character
>   is slain. If they were wrong, they cannot vote anymore.
>   Each vote you received is another five points added to your score.
>   The character with the highest score has been tested by the City and
>   found acceptable. That character is allowed to enter, while the rest are
>   left in the wilderness. If there is a tie, the miraculous happens - they
>   are both admitted to the City.
>
> Every player should tell in one or two sentences the resolution to the
>   problem their character had, the reason they were searching for the
>   City. If they made it, did they find what they were seeking in the City
>   of Brass? If they died or didn’t get admitted to the City, what horrible
>   things happened?